# Grep contents recursively, print only 1 directory level deep

Tags: grep, recursive

I want to search within file contents, recursively on subdirectories, but I only care about whether the first level subdirectory contains any matches. That is, given:

```
ParentDirectory
    Subdirectory1
        File containing match
        File not containing match
        File containing match
    Subdirectory2
        File not containing match
        File not containing match
    Subdirectory3
        File not containing match
        Subdirectory3.1
            File containing match
```

I need to know:

```
Matches:
ParentDirectory/Subdirectory1
ParentDirectory/Subdirectory3
```

Can someone provide a way to do this with grep or similar utility?

Comment: So you have to search all of the subdirectories, but you only want to *report* matches based on the first-level subdirectory?

Comment: What I'm trying to clarify is that you don't need files that are directly in "subdirectory3" to match in order to report it.

Comment: @jeff-Schaller yes (which also means search can stop at first match in a given level of subdirectory)

Comment: I'd do it with `find` and a `maxdepth` to limit what files are looked in, then use the `-exec`  option for your grep or pipe through `xargs`.  `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f  -exec grep -H searchterm {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

**Use `find` to run recursive `grep` on each subdirectory:**

```
echo "Matches:"
find ParentDirectory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -exec grep -rq pattern {} \; \
  -and -print
```

`-q` option lets `grep` stop at first match
`-and -print` will make `find` print the directory only when `grep` found something.

---

**Alternative with a `for`-loop:**

```
echo "Matches:"
for d in ParentDirectory/* ; do
    [ -d "$d" ] && grep -rq pattern "$d" && echo "$d"
done
```

**Output for either version:**

```
Matches:
ParentDirectory/Subdirectory1
ParentDirectory/Subdirectory3
```